# How to use the data from an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following JQuery AJAX call which successfully returns data from the database -

```
$.ajax({
   url : 'get_hashtags.php',
   type : 'GET',
   success : function(data){
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      console.log(obj);
   }
});
```

This is the data returned -

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0
:
{category: "ht.austria"}
1
:
{category: "ht.landscapes"}
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

Now I'd like to use the data returned from the database as the suggestions in the following Javascript code. So instead of the "suggestions" like ht.austria it should use the data returned from the DB.

```
$('#inputTags').amsifySuggestags({
    suggestions: ['ht.austria','ht.landscape'],
    classes: ['bg-warning','bg-warning'],
});
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried calling a function in the success part of the Ajax call, but getting an error message that amsifySuggestags is not a function. Can anyone help please?

***Update***

I've now tried with the following code as suggested by Shiv, but I still get an error -

```
$.ajax({
   url : 'get_hashtags.php',
   type : 'GET',
   success : function(data){
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      console.log(obj);
      var suggestionsArr = []; 

      obj.forEach(function(item){ 
        suggestionsArr.push(item.category) 
      });

      createHashtags(suggestionsArr);
   }
});

function createHashtags(data)
{
    $('#inputTags').amsifySuggestags({
        suggestions: data,
        classes: ['bg-warning','bg-warning'],
    });
}
```

This is the error I'm getting -

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).amsifySuggestags is not a function
at createHashtags (upload.php:1557)
at Object.success (upload.php:1551)
at i (VM392 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM392 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at A (VM392 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM392 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

Comment: Please don't extend questions after they've been answered. As far as that error is concerned, it means that whatever jQuery plugin you're using has not be loaded.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Didn't know how else to ask this question. Strange that I can call the amsifySuggestags outside the function, but it doesn't work inside the Javascript function.

Comment: You can ask the new question by clicking the Ask Question button, same as you did with this one... You should probably do some research first though, as "TypeError:  is not a function" is a very common error.

Comment: Okay, will do. I just didn't reply as a comment so that I can include all the source code changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extract `category` data by looping `obj` and push into an Array and use.

look into code snippe.

```js
var obj = [
  {category: "ht.austria"},
  {category: "ht.landscapes"}
];

var suggestionsArr = [];

obj.forEach(function(item){ 
  suggestionsArr.push(item.category) 
});


console.log('suggestionsArr : ', suggestionsArr);


   /* $('#inputTags').amsifySuggestags({
    suggestions: suggestionsArr,
    classes: ['bg-warning','bg-warning'],
}); */
```

Comment: Thanks Shiv. I've tested it, but I'm still getting an error. Do you have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: I've included it in the original post. The error is "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).amsifySuggestags is not a function". Couldn't figure out what the problem is yet. I'm using the following plugin - https://github.com/amsify42/jquery.amsify.suggestags. When calling $('#inputTags').amsifySuggestags outside a function it works correctly, but inside the function createHashtags I'm getting this error.

Comment: disregard. final solution can be found here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52818048/javascript-typeerror-functionname-is-not-a-function