# Javascript TypeError $(...).functionName is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch

I'm using the following Javascript to get data via PHP (**upload.php**) -

```
<script src="js/jquery.amsify.suggestags.js"></script>

<script>
fetch('./get_hashtags.php').then(response => {
  return response.json();
}).then(data => {        
    var suggestionsArr = [];

    data.forEach(function(item){ 
        suggestionsArr.push(item.category);
    });

    console.log(suggestionsArr);

    $('#inputTags').amsifySuggestags({
        suggestions: suggestionsArr,
        classes: ['bg-warning','bg-warning'],
    });
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
</script>
```

**get_hashtags.php**

```
<?php
// ... some additional database connection details ...
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT category FROM hashtags where active=1");

$hashtags = array();
if ($statement->execute()) {
    while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $hashtags[] = $row;
    }
}

$pdo = null;

echo json_encode($hashtags);
?>
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error when loading the page -

```
TypeError: $(...).amsifySuggestags is not a function
at fetch.then.then.data (upload.php:1550)
```

This is the beginning of **jquery.amsify.suggestags.js** (https://github.com/amsify42/jquery.amsify.suggestags) -

```
(function($) {

$.fn.amsifySuggestags = function(options, method) {
    /**
     * Merging default settings with custom
     * @type {object}
     */
    var settings = $.extend({
        type          : 'bootstrap',
        tagLimit      : 5,
        suggestions   : [],
        classes       : [],
        backgrounds   : [],
        colors        : [],
        whiteList     : false,
        afterAdd      : {},
        afterRemove   : {},
    }, options);

    /**
     * Initialization begins from here
     * @type {Object}
     */
    var AmsifySuggestags = function() {
        this.selector      = null;
        this.name          = null;
...
```

I don't get the error message when inserting the $('#inputTags').amsifySuggestags outside of the fetch method with some hardcoded values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you somehow include more than one version of jQuery?

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=typeerror+is+not+a+function+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @mplungjan how are those duplicates? OP did not say that `$` is undefined

Comment: This is clearly *not* a problem involving jQuery itself not being imported. It's likely to be a problem of jQuery being imported *twice* but without confirmation the posted code does not show evidence of that.

Comment: Thanks epascarello and Pointy. You were right! I had jQuery included twice. Not sure why this wasn't causing issues before, but only when starting to include the "fetch" call.

Comment: @epascarello - a bit premature. It was a dupe though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801122/how-to-use-the-data-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: not really a dupe since I was asked to create a new one.